# using for with sub name in vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
private sub sub1()
sub1.value=true
end sub    

private sub sub2()
sub2.value=true
end sub

private sub sub3()
sub3.value=true
end sub
```

how could I write following code in a true way ?

```
dim x as integer    
for x = 1 to 3

private sub subx()
subx.value=true
end sub
```

Comment: You may be really over-simplifying your actual use case, but it's hard to see what the aim is here.  Seems like you could more easily use an array of booleans.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You'd be better off defining a `Class Module`, then creating an array of objects of that class. For example, if you have a class named `Automobile`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private mySpeed As Double

Public Property Let Speed(ByVal newSpeed)
    mySpeed = newSpeed
End Property

Public Property Get Speed() As Double
    Speed = mySpeed
End Property

Private Sub class_initialize()
    mySpeed = 0#
End Sub
```

Then in a regular `Module` you can define:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim autos(1 To 5) As Automobile
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 5
        Set autos(i) = New Automobile
        autos(i).Speed = i * 15#
    Next i
End Sub
```